# how to create a sub vector from the original vector in stata

Tags: vector, stata

I have a vector x of 12 elements. I want to create a sub vector of 4 elements which include the first 4 elements of x.

Answer (score 0):

What did you read? What code did you try? `help matrix` leads directly to help on matrix extraction. Consider the results of code like

```
mat foo = J(12,1,1)
mat foo4 = foo[1..4, 1]
mat li foo4
```